# Merge branch in GIT and keep the commit message

Tags: git, merge, branch, message, commit

I want to merge a branch in GIT and keep the COMMIT MESSAGE.

[image]

***Not wanted***: `git merge --no-edit`
This keeps the default message: *Merge branch 'master' into develop*

***Wanted***: I want to copy the message: *ACC-9187 Reformat code* instead of the *Merge branch ....*. ==> The merge must contain the same message.
Offcourse I don't want to type the whole message again...: ***not:*** `git merge -m "ACC-9187 Reformat code"`

**==> Any suggestions? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the merge is done and before you make any new commit, run:

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD^2
```

If you want a single-line solution:

```
git merge master -m "$(git log -1 --pretty=%B master)"
```